# How to put multiple images on a single product with Magmi?

Tags: product-images, magmi

I just found out Magmi for the import of the products. It is beautiful and perfect when you full of products... But I was wondering how to put multiple images on a single product with Magmi?

Comment: Please edit your question, explain what you have tried, what happened and what you expected.

Answer (score 1):

You use the `media_gallery` column.

http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor

Comment: Thank you it is possible to create of the configurable product with magmi and wanted to associate simple products?

Comment: Yeah, you can do that with Magmi. Check out the wiki link I posted. The guide is very thorough. Magmi can do almost everything, if not everything, you can do in the admin.